# Openvswitch (ovsdb) database migration

Tags: openstack-neutron, openvswitch

We have an Openstack infrastructure consisting of one controller node, eight compute nodes and a network node. This last node is having hardware problems (disk write failures). Unfortunately it has only one disk without replication. And there's no option now to modify it for HA support.

We already tried to "dd" that disk to another but it didn't bring up. So, we agreed that the better choice was to build a new network node (using the same hardware specs)

Failing network node is running the following:

- CentOS 7.1.1503
- Openstack-neutron-openvswitch-2014.2.2-1 (Juno release)
- Openvswitch-2.1.2-2

New network node:

- CentOS 7.3.1611
- Openstack-neutron-openvswitch-2014.2.3-1 (Juno release)
- Openvswitch-2.3.1-2

We managed to export the database, just copying the conf.db file located in /etc/openvswitch into the new node. We had to convert the db to a newer schema since the nodes have different ovs versions. But we can't make it work like the old one, since it adds new interfaces to the database record and doesn't use the ones imported from the old hardware, even having the same exact names.

Is there a way to replicate the ovs configuration in the new node and make it work? That considering that both hardware are the same. Any of you had any experience trying to move/import/export an ovs database? I can attach the database dump if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must config manually from the beginning, because that database is hashed and encrypted,
when you install openstack throught different machine, the openstack generate keystone randomly,
if you use packstack it the keystone stone can be same with you generate the answer-file

```
packstack --gen-answer-file=openstack.conf
```

and adit the option you want in `openstack.conf`